# Android Download File from webserver using Volley

Tags: java, android, download, android-volley

Sorry I am a newbie with Android developing an app which sell digital downloads. I am using Volley Library to post INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA and INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE to webserver to verify order and issue download link passing

```
http://domain.com/thankyou.php?purchaseData="+purchaseData+"&dataSignature="+dataSignature+"
```

If the order is verified a download link will be issued inside the page.  The file name isn't static which means it's auto-generate by system so I can't guess the name each time issued from the server side. Can be file1.dat file2.dat file3.dat each time has a name depending on certain parameters I defined into the webserver.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Thank You</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://domain.com/file.dat" title="Order" download>Download File</a>   
</body>
</html>
```

Now I need to post the download file link to the app so the customer can download the file.

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

//download file on through a new in-app page
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            })
```

I have created an `activity_download.xml` file and a new Download Class.

```
package com.example.app;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.example.app.R;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Download extends Activity {

private String filename;

@Override
protected void onCreate (final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);
    }
}

}
```

Sorry again I am a newbie with Android. Can you guide me a provide me with a way to have a complete Download.java class as a new page and then call it from the MainActivity.java side onresponse and successful result.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Cange your MainActivity code to this.

```
         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Download.class);
                           startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                })
```

As you want make a toast as soon as you get a Respons. dont do it in Activity class, do it in Download class becasue you will redirected to Download class soon as you get the response

```
  public class Download extends Activity {

  private String filename;

@Override
protected void onCreate (final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);
//download file on through a new in-app page
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for the share. Toast isn't necessary I just was using it to verify I'm received the correct result however what I need is to GET the download link of the file and redirect the customer inside the app itself to a separate page where it says "Thank you for you purchase!" and under it a Download Button to download the file.